# Running code until button is pressed

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity that starts after a certain time. Once this activity starts, the user is supposed to press a button that starts a new timer.

However, if the user does not press the button I want a toast to be displayed every 5 minutes until the button is pressed.

I have a listener for the button:

```
    startBreakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startBreakButton);
    startBreakButton.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);
```

I have the code for displaying the toast and everything else is working well.

I'm just not sure where to put the code I want to run before the button is clicked. Within the mStartListener code or somewhere else such as within the onCreate method?

**UPDATE**

```
 public class BreakActivity extends Activity {

Button startBreakButton; // button to start the break timer
Boolean clicked= false;
CountDownTimer counter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.breakscreen); // sets layout to breakscreen.xml

    MyCount counter;
    counter=new MyCount(5000,1000);
    counter.start();

  startBreakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startBreakButton);
    startBreakButton.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);

  View.OnClickListener mStartListener = new OnClickListener() { 

 clicked=true;
 //other listener code
 };

 public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
    public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
      if(clicked==false){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TAKE A BREAK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        counter= new MyCount(5000,1000);
     counter.start();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        long s1 = millisUntilFinished;

    }
    }
    };
```

EDIT - Above solution is not working, it needed to be clicked==false, not clicked=false!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this..

in oncreate create a acountdowntimer..

```
 MyCount counter;
 counter=new MyCount(300000,1000);
 counter.start();
```

MyCount class..

```
   public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
}
@Override
public void onFinish() {
  if(clicked=false){
  //put the toast here
    counter= new MyCount(300000,1000);
 counter.start();
    }

}
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    s1=millisUntilFinished;



}
}
}
```

and in onclicklistener of startBreakButton put

```
clicked=true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The activity where I want this to occur is called BreakActivity. Do i put the first code snippet in the onCreate method of this activity along with the third code snippet in the listener. For the second code snippet do I need to create that class and extend BreakActivity?

Comment: Ok,I've added class myCount at the end of the BreakActivity. However, in the class myCount is says that variables counter, clicked and s1 are undefined. The clicked=true that I added to the Startlistener cannot be resolved to a variable so its gone wrong somewhere :(

Comment: create a boolean clicked=false.. initially..before onCreate..so that it is available to all functions

Comment: Thanks, thats got rid of the clicked errors, I'm guessing I need to do the same for counter and s1 varables. For s1 shal I just do quick fix 'Create local variable'?

Comment: I've got no errors now but the toasts are not being displayed. I will update my post to show how the code is set up.

Comment: I've updated my post to hopefully you can see whats wrong :D
If i put the myCount class after the BreakActivity class is closed it says it should be placed in another file, at the moment its inside the activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AlarmManager to set an alarm for 5mins from now.

Then check if the user didn't click the button, show the toast and set another alarm. If the user clicked the button, do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a flag that determines whether button is clicked or not. 
If it is clicked then make that flag true. 
If flag is false then call method in every 5 minutes which will toast to press button.
You can call schedule method in every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the toast code inside the onClicklistener method.Use if condition to know the state of the button whether it is pressed or not.I hope it will work.